# Bamboo parent-child build plans

Tags: bamboo

I'm new to bamboo.

I have a bunch of build plans that build individual software components (deployable assets) that all run based upon polling the git repo.  I'm trying to set up a build pipeline that will take the list of deployable assets and deploy them to a "CI" server and run a series of automated tests.  Based upon test results, the deployable assets can be pushed to downstream target environments.

This issue with triggering this off of individual deployable assets is that a single commit can trigger a CI deployment and that asset may have a dependency on another asset that has yet to be built.  What I would like to do in Bamboo is have a "parent" plan that I can run, that will run through the build plans for each individual asset and look for changes and then I would package all of the built assets and push to the CI and test.

Is there a way in bamboo that I can control this process through a parent plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a 'parent' plan where you can add the tasks to download the latest Artifacts from your 'child' plans, and attach deployment only to this plan. You can trigger this plan when you need, or add child plans (Dependencies) in plan configuration, so you will get a new parent build, as soon as one of the child builds was created.
You can read more about plan dependencies here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/setting-up-plan-build-dependencies-289276887.html

Comment: I was able to set up a successful parent child dependency and get the parent to trigger child builds.  How do i access the build artifacts from the child plan?  Is there a task or api call that will enable me to "harvest" the child plan build assets in the parent?

Comment: yes, there is a task called "Artifact download". It will download the artifact from selected plan to working directory. But I think first you need to make your child's artifact "Shared". There is more information here with instructions - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/sharing-artifacts-359400060.html